# I'm stuck. I need to adjust my loops so they continue to compare my two arrays but not print out all the extra characters

Tags: java, arrays

I have to compare two string arrays. If the any of the characters in myArray match a character in argArray then I need to swap the case of the character in myArray. I'm almost there but am getting extra output.

This is what I have so far -

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Main ob = new Main();
        ob.reverse("bcdxyz@3210.");

    }
    public String reverse(String arg) {

        String reverseCap = "";
        String myStr = "abc, XYZ; 123.";

        char[] argArray = arg.toCharArray();
        char[] myArray = myStr.toCharArray();

        for (int i =0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j =0; j < argArray.length; j++){
                if (myArray[i] == argArray[j] && Character.isLowerCase(myArray[i])){
                    reverseCap += Character.toUpperCase(myArray[i]);
                } else if (myArray[i] == argArray[j] && Character.isUpperCase(myArray[i])){
                    reverseCap += Character.toLowerCase(myArray[i]);
                } else {
                    reverseCap += myArray[i];
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(reverseCap);
        return null;
    }
```

I want reverseCap to be "aBC, xyz, 123." but am getting the following -

```
"aaaaaaaaaaaaBbbbbbbbbbbbcCcccccccccc,,,,,,,,,,,,            XXXXXXXXXXXXYYYYYYYYYYYYZZZZZZZZZZZZ;;;;;;;;;;;;            111111111111222222222222333333333333............
".
```

I've been staring at this for hours so I figured it was time to ask for help before I pluck my eyes out.

Comment: Consider using a `StringBuilder` to model the String you are manipulating.  You may find it easier to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marce noted the problem of adding characters to `reverseCap` on every iteration.  Here is a solution that solves that problem and performs the case changes in place.  Checking for a match first and then changing the case simplifies the logic a bit.  Note `myArray[i]` needs to be lowercased before checking against `arg[i]` because the former may be an uppercase character; this is not needed for `argArray[j]` because those characters are assumed to be all lowercase.  Finally, once the inner loop has matched, further iterations of it are no longer needed.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Main ob = new Main();
        String testStr = "abc, XYZ; 123.";
        String testArg = "bcdxyz@3210.";
        System.out.println(testStr + " using " + testArg + " =>");
        System.out.println(ob.reverse(testStr, testArg));
    }

    public String reverse(String myStr, String myArg) {

        char[] myArray = myStr.toCharArray();
        char[] argArray = myArg.toCharArray();

        for (int i =0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j =0; j < argArray.length; j++) {
                if (Character.toLowerCase(myArray[i]) == argArray[j]) {
                    if (Character.isLowerCase(myArray[i])) {
                        myArray[i] = Character.toUpperCase(myArray[i]);
                    } else if (Character.isUpperCase(myArray[i])) {
                        myArray[i] = Character.toLowerCase(myArray[i]);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return String.valueOf(myArray);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With this part

```
} else {
    reverseCap += myArray[i];
}
```

you're adding a character to `reverseCap` with every iteration, regardless if the characters match or not.

In your specific example, you could just leave that out, since every character in `myStr` also appears in `arg`, but if you want to add characters to `reverseCap`, even if they don't appear in `arg`, you'll need a way of checking if you already added a character to `reverseCap`.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
String reverseCap = "";
```

to

```
char[] reverseCap = new char[myStr.length()];
```

and then for each occurrence of

```
reverseCap +=
```

change that to read

```
reverseCap[i] =
```

Finally, convert `reverseCap` to a String:

```
String result = String.valueOf(reverseCap);
```

You are currently returning `null`. Consider returning `result`, and moving the `System.out.println(...)` into the `main()` method.

Update:
I think a better way to approach this is to use a lookup map containing upper/lower case pairs and their inverse to get the replacement character. The nested for loops are a bit gnarly.

```
    /**
     * Example: for the string "bcdxyz@3210."
     * the lookup map is 
     * {B=b, b=B, C=c, c=C, D=d, d=D, X=x, x=X, Y=y, y=Y, Z=z, z=Z}
     * <p>
     * Using a map to get the inverse of a character is faster than repetitively 
     * looping through the string.
     * </p>
     * @param arg
     * @return
     */
    public String reverse2(String arg) {
        Map<Character, Character> inverseLookup = createInverseLookupMap(arg);
        
        String myStr = "abc, XYZ; 123.";
        String result = myStr.chars()
            .mapToObj(ch -> Character.toString(inverseLookup.getOrDefault(ch, (char) ch)))
            .collect(Collectors.joining());

        return result;
    }

    private Map<Character, Character> createInverseLookupMap(String arg) {
        Map<Character, Character> lookupMap = arg.chars()
            .filter(ch -> Character.isLetter(ch))
            .mapToObj(this::getPairs)
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Pair::key, Pair::value));

        System.out.println(lookupMap);
        return lookupMap;
    }

    private List<Pair> getPairs(int ch) {
        char upperVariant = (char) Character.toUpperCase(ch);
        return List.of(
            new Pair(upperVariant, Character.toLowerCase(upperVariant)),
            new Pair(Character.toLowerCase(upperVariant), upperVariant));
    }

    static record Pair(Character key, Character value) {
    }
```

But if one is not used to the Java streaming API, this might look a bit gnarly too.